# How can I get a value from user and use it in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a quiz game and want to allow an user to choose game difficulty. I have a JSON list, which includes questions.

```
var easy = '[{"eser":"Question1","yazar":"Answer1"},{"eser":"Question2","yazar":"Answer2"}]';
var hard = '[{"eser":"Question3","yazar":"Answer3"},{"eser":"Question4","yazar":"Answer4"}]';
```

and I parse it like below

```
difficulty = JSON.parse(easy);
var count = Object.keys(difficulty).length;
```

When the game opens, it shows a popup which wants from user to select difficulty. Basically when user click Hard, I want to catch it and change the code above as `difficulty = JSON.parse(hard);`

HTML code is here

```
<div class="button_easy">Easy</div>
<div class="button_hard">Hard</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Code is missing

Comment: @chevybow which part is missing?

Comment: the html code is missing

Comment: @JSmith Okay I forgot to write it as a code. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use separate variables, use an object whose keys correspond to something in the element they select.

```
const questions = {
    easy: [{"eser":"Question1","yazar":"Answer1"},{"eser":"Question2","yazar":"Answer2"}],
    hard: [{"eser":"Question3","yazar":"Answer3"},{"eser":"Question4","yazar":"Answer4"}]
};
```

The HTML can be like:

```
<div class="difficulty" data-level="easy">Easy</div>
<div class="difficulty" data-level="hard">Hard</div>
```

And the JS would be:

```
let chosen_questions;
document.querySelector(".difficulty").forEach(b => b.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let level = this.dataset.level;
    chosen_questions = questions[level];
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with `eval` function (error handling is omitted here if there is no such variable named the string represented by `user_choice`):

```
 var difficulty = JSON.parse(eval(user_choice))
```

But I think it might be better to put those two lists inside a dictionary like this:

```
var difficulty_dic = {
  'easy': easy,
  'hard': hard
}
```

And later you can do something like:

```
var difficulty = JSON.parse(difficulty_dic[user_choice])
```